# Classifying dataset with different number of features

Tags: machine-learning, classification, feature-selection, multi-class

I have a dataset like below:

```
samplename position reference alternative
S1 201 C T
S1 3567 A G
S1 760 T C
S2 356 C T
S2 6787 T C
```

These data belongs to patients and their genomic variants. I have the label for each patients as for example S1 labeled 'Control' and S2 labeled 'Disease'. I would like to be able to classify my patients based on their variants. How I can do it?

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Are S1 and S2 patient ids? If that's so, each patient can have different number of variants I believe?

Comment: Yes @gunes these are patient ids and each patient can have different number of variants. Do you have any idea how should I classify the patients?